# Кто должен выполнять функционал? (Компонент Joomla)

Tags: joomla, mvc, архитектура

Доборого времени суток.
Я разрабатываю компонент для joomla, используя паттерн MVC. У меня возникла дилемма -
кто должен выполнять нетривиальный функционал (подготовить и отправить email, пропарсить и обработать страницы с другого сайта и.т.д) -  модель, контроллер, функции внешнего класса в модели, функции внешнего класса в контроллере  или что-то другое?